# Symfony2 Doctrine2 use of partials

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

From reading the documentation and another stackoverflow post, I thought that if I only want to return a couple of columns data, the correct method in doctrine was to use a partial. (This is a read only query).

However the below code returns all 100 columns instead of the 3 I identified. Can someone explain why?

Thanks,
Manisha

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
        $id = $request->get('locationid');
        $kfType = $request->get('type');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();

        $data = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select ( array( 'partial d.{id, locationid, kfFyp}' ))
                    ->from('DashDataBundle:Data',  'd')
                    ->where('d.locationid = :locationid')
                    ->setParameter('locationid', $id)
                    ->setMaxResults(100)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return doctrine entities which have many fields. But then you use `partial` keywords this fields would be empty. Only specified fields would be filled with data.

If you doesnt want to hydrate objects you can get data in simple array if you specify it

```
->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
```

Comment: Thank you! That made it work as I was hoping, showing only the fields I asked for in the returned array instead of the whole object.

Comment: Since I'm not using whole object, is should I bother with QueryBuilder? Better to just use DQL?

Comment: no big difference. may be pure dql little faster. it just builds queries at all, nothing else